# Solve: $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} x e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2} \, dx \\[6pt]
& =\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2} \, dx+\int_{-\infty}^{0} x e^{-x^2} \, dx \\[6pt]  
& =-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{-\infty} e^t \, dt-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^t \, dt \\[6pt]
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^0 e^t \, dt-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^t \, dt \\[6pt] 
& =0
\end{align}
$$

I can't understand the third line.
It means that we substitute $x^2=t$ and $dx=dt/2x$? But I think it doesn't make sense...

Comment: Right, it doesn't make sense. When substituting $t = x^2$, the factor $x$ of the integrand is absorbed into $dt$ and hence must go.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then what is the right answer? $0$ is the right answer?

Comment: Yes, the integral is $0$. Quick computationless method: the integrand is an odd function, the interval of integration is symmetric about $0$, and the integral exists. Other method: $$\int_a^b xe^{-x^2}\,dx = \left[-\frac12 e^{-x^2}\right]_a^b = \frac{e^{-a^2} - e^{-b^2}}{2},$$ let $a\to -\infty$ and $b\to +\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry! I made a huge mistake and fix it now. $x$ is gone and I wonder why $-$ and $-\infty$ in the third line appear?

Comment: Ah, the substitution is $t = -x^2$, not $t = x^2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, then I understand $-\frac{1}{2}$. But where does $-\infty$ come from? Also, if we put $-$ into the interal, we can change $\int_{0}^{-\infty}$ to $\int_{-\infty}^{0}$ like forth line?

Comment: When $x = +\infty$, then $t = -x^2 = -\infty$. That's why the integral limit $+\infty$ becomes $-\infty$ after the substitution.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I understand completely! Thanks a lot!

Comment: A too-loose use of the point about odd functions would lead us to conclude that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx=0$.  I suppose there is a sense in which that is true, but probably this conclusion that the value is $0$ should be accompanied by some account of just which sense that is.  However, evaluating this particular integral by substitution methods involving the chain rule is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Define the variable $z= x\sqrt2$. Then $x = \frac{z}{\sqrt2}$ and $dx = \frac{dz}{\sqrt2}$.
Insert into the integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z\frac {1}{\sqrt2} e^{-\frac 12z^2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}ze^{-\frac 12z^2}dz$$
The integral now represents the expected value of the standard normal distribution, which is zero.

From a amthematical point of view, one could show the initial intergal is zero by

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} x e^{-x^2}dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2}dx$$

Swap the limits of integration in the first integral and obtain a minus sign

$$I =  - \int_{0}^{-\infty} x e^{-x^2}dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2}dx$$

We have by the properties of the integral
$$- \int_{0}^{-\infty} x e^{-x^2}dx = \int_{(-1)\cdot 0}^{(-1)\cdot -\infty} (-x) e^{-(-x)^2}dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-x^2}dx $$

Substitute into $I$

$$I =  -\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-x^2}dx  + \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2}dx =0$$

...which is the "odd function" property mentioned by others.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you do not need to evaluate the integral. It equals to zero, since the integrand

> $$ f(x)=xe^{-x^2} $$

is an odd function.

**Note:**

> The integral of an odd function on the interval $[-a,a]$ is $0$.

Comment: One would still need to show that the improper integral makes sense. $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} x dx$ is not zero, but $x$ is an odd function. That's important for someone at lower levels of practice.